# React-Native Firebase custom events not showing in DebugView mode on iOS

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

So I followed all the [instructions](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.1.x/installation/), installed the library and linked it with `react-native link react-native-firebase`

Added the [correct code](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.1.x/installation/ios) in my `AppDelegate.m` with my `GoogleService-Info.plist` file added in my XCode project.

I also added `-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` and `-FIRDebugEnabled` in the Arguments Passed On Launch like the [documentation said](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#enabling_debug_mode).

Events like: `user_engagement` and `first_open` are showing correctly so I'm guessing that my config is OK, but my custom events aren't showing at all in the DebugView.

In [React-Native-Firebase documentation it says](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.1.x/installation/ios#1.2.-Initialise-Firebase)

> The default app is pre-initialized natively therefore there is no need to call initializeApp for the default app instance.

But in [this example](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/174) that I tried to follow, he uses `initializeApp` with for parameter `debug: false` so that events show up.

Code that I tried:

```
import RNFirebase from 'react-native-firebase';

const firebaseApp = RNFirebase.initializeApp({ debug: false });
firebaseApp.analytics().logEvent("test_event");
```

I did the same thing and it's not working at all. What is the correct syntax to send events on DebugView? I'm a little lost here. Thanks!

I'm using RN: 0.52.0

Comment: late to the party - did you manage to have custom events showing up in the firebase console?

Comment: It was an old project I used to work on, but if I remember it took some times before it updates and it did work it just wasn't instantly. Keep me posted if it works!

Comment: On Android I had to enable debug mode for analytics: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#enabling_debug_mode. 

After that the events will be visible in realtime in the firebase consoles debug view stream.